# Reading large file using BufferedReader and a String is returned for each line is there a potential out of memory issue?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Using the standard Java idiom

```
while ((line = bufferedReaderVrdDatafile.readLine()) != null) {
   doSomething;
}
```

The file has 1M lines.  Does that mean that 1M strings will be created given the String is immutable?

Comment: If the whole file is a single line, then yes. It will only allocate the amount of memory it is needed for a single line. If your file is split into many lines, then you don't have a problem.

Comment: Yes it does mean that 1M `Strings` will be created. But there is nothing that obliges you to hold all 1M in memory at the same time. Any input file can be processed a line or indeed a character at a time. Compilers do it: so can you.

Comment: The strings that are no longer reachable will be garbage-collected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for each line a new String instance will be created. But the Garbage Collector will automatically remove instances that are no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks.  So "line" gets filled by readline();  and then on next iteration line gets another String and because nothing is referencing the first String it get Garbage Collected from the string pool?

Comment: Exactly. The instance formerly assigned to "line" will no longer be referenced anywhere and therefore be eligible for garbage collection.